# Why is the graph of $y = \mathrm{arcsin}(e^x) $ and $y = e^{(3e/2) + x}$ the same?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

[The graphs:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HmWg.png)

Is there any mathematical reasons as to why the graphs of $y = \mathrm{arcsin}(e^x) $ and $y = e^{(3e/2) + x}$ look the same?

Comment: Zoom in. Zoom in _good_, and you should see a difference. They just look identical from afar.

Comment: If $y=\arcsin(e^x)$, then $e^x=\sin(y)$. But$$y=e^{3e/2+x}=e^{3e/2} \sin(y) \implies \frac y{\sin(y)} = \text{constant}$$which is not true.

Comment: That can't be the two graphs, because $\arcsin$ has a maximum value of $\pi/2.$

Comment: As a rule, $\arcsin(y)\approx y,$ as $y$ gets close to $0,$ so $\arcsin(e^x)\approx e^x,$ while  $e^{3e/2+x}=e^{3e/2}\cdot e^x\approx 59e^x.$ Maybe you are working in degrees rather than radians? Then $\arcsin(e^x)\approx 57e^x$ when $e^x$ is small, so at least they are close as $e^x\to 0$ and you get an the curve goes out of the range here (to $90.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I could reproduce your graph by setting to use degrees rather than radians. If $\arcsin_d$ is the degree version of $\arcsin,$ then: $$\arcsin_d(y)=\frac{180}\pi \arcsin(y).$$

Mathematicians tend to use radian only, so you can understand the confusion.

Now, for $y$ close to zero $\arcsin(y)\sim y.$ And thus $\arcsin_d(y)\sim \frac{180}{\pi}y.$

So for large negative values of $x,$ we have $f(x)=\arcsin(e^x)\sim\frac{180}{\pi}e^x.$

For any $x,$ $g(x)=e^{3e/2+x}=e^{3e/2}e^x.$

Now, $e^{3e/2}\approx 58.99,$ while $\frac{180}\pi\approx 57.30.$ So as $x\to -\infty,$ $g(x)$ will be 3% bigger than $f(x).$

But $f(1)=90,$ and $g(1)\approx 58.99,$ so they are not going to agree when $x$ is close to zero.

If we instead graph $p(x)=\arcsin_d(x)$ and $q(x)=x\cdot e^{3e/2}$ on $[0,1],$ we get this graph:

[image: related graph]

Your change to use $p(e^x)$ and $q(e^x),$ and the choice of the top $y$ value to be $50$ seems to select the values of $e^x$ where $\arcsin_d(e^x)$ is closer to $\frac{180}\pi e^x.$

When $x=-1,$ $e^{x}<0.4,$ and as you can see at that point $\arcsin(0.4)$ is pretty close to $\frac{180}{\pi}\cdot 0.4.$ The scale of your $x$ values leaves the range where these functions greatly disagree to a tiny region.

So what you are really noticing is that $\frac{180}{\pi}$ is not very far from $e^{3e/2},$ and $\arcsin_d(z)$ is fairly linear relatively far from $z=0.$

If you zoom into my graph as $x$ is close to zero, you see:
[image]

That difference is the 3% difference I spoke of above.

Here's a simple graph in radians, compare $\arcsin(e^x)$ and $e^x,$ similar to your graph. The key is that there is really only a visible difference when $-2<x<0.$ The choice to scale the $x$ axis to dwarf that region means we are emphasizing the values where $e^x$ is very small, and thus where $\arcsin(e^x)$ is close to $e^x.$

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that a certain coefficient of e can perfectly replicate the graph of arcsin(e^x)?

Comment: Nope, the best coefficient of $e^x$ will be $\frac{180}\pi,$ which will match the slope in by graph of $\arcsin(y)$ and $\frac{180}\pi y.$ @FahadHassan

Answer (score 2):

As per your question these are the graphs. The blue color curve and green color curve are $y=\arcsin(e^x)$ and $y=e^{\frac32e+x}$ respectively:

[image]

Comment: I suspect the OP was returning degrees, rather than radians, from $\arcsin.$ Then the graph is not so distinct, but not the same, either. Then, as $x\to-\infty,$ $\arcsin(e^x)\sim \frac{180}{\pi}e^x$ and the other function is $e^{3e/2}e^x,$ and $e^{3e/2}\approx \frac{180}{\pi},$ for some loose definitions of $\approx.$